# Formatting a date for output

Tags: javascript, facebook

How I can format a date string using Javascript. For example:

```
var date_str = "2010-10-06T03:39:41+0000";
```

The result should be like this:

```
11:39 AM Oct 6th
```

Is there any ideas on this? Note: date_str is an example of returned date from Facebook Graph API.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What significance is the 'T' in the middle of `date_str`? I assume it relates to how we get from 03:39 to 11:39..

Comment: I think so..its just the returned string from Facebook API..

Comment: @ElRonnoco: This is an ISO8601 date, the `+0000` depicts that the timezone offset is +0 from UTC.  Facebook probably just displays this date in @Trez's local timezone as 11:39AM (+8 hours).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing the date shouldn't be too difficult - all the components are in the right order so you just need to split on the special characters, subtract 1 from the month value and apply the array, minus the last element, to *Date.UTC()*:

```
function parseDate(dStr) {
    var d    = dStr.split(/[-:T+]/); d[1] -= 1; d.pop();
    var date = new Date(Date.UTC.apply(Date, d));
```

This gives us a *Date* object for the date specified, the rest is just formatting each component back into a string:

```
    // Declare an array of short month names
    var mon  = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov", "Dec"];
    // Determine between AM and PM
        ampm = date.getHours() > 12 ? "PM" : "AM",

    // Prepare for working out the date suffix
        nth  = date.getDate();

    // Date is nth for 11th, 12th and 13th
    if (nth >= 11 && nth <= 13)
        nth = "th";
    // Otherwise it's st, nd, rd, th if the date ends in 1, 2, 3 or anything else
    else
        nth  = ["", "st", "nd", "rd"][(nth+"").slice(-1)] || "th";

    // Return the string formatted date
    return (date.getHours() % 12) + ":" + (date.getMinutes()) + " " + ampm +
           " " + mon[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate() + nth;
}

// Example:
parseDate("2010-10-06T03:39:41+0000");
// -> "4:39 AM Oct 6th" (in my timezone)
```

If you want the output to be the same regardless of timezone (the original time supplied), you need to swap the methods *getHours()*, *getMinutes()*, etc for *getUTCHours()*, *getUTCMinutes()*, etc.

Comment: @Trez: I noticed a small error with the date suffix part, I've fixed it now.  Hopefully you'll see this before you go ahead and implement the solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function from phpjs.org: http://phpjs.org/functions/date:380

Comment: date(format, timestamp) is ok but the problem is how to convert the date_str to timestamp so that i can pass it to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Date.parse can parse this if you strip the +0000 part. You can then use setTime on a Date object, which you can pretty print yourself, or using some library.